# Is it a coincidence that both Supergirl and Captain Marvel are named Danvers?

Tags: marvel, dc

Supergirl is named Kara Danvers (by adoption), and in the latest TV-show iteration, works with her sister Alex Danvers.

Captain Marvel (upcoming movie version) is named Carol Danvers.

Any connection, relation, shout-out, anything like that?

Comment: [Answers here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-a-coincidence-that-Captain-Marvel-and-Supergirl-have-the-same-last-name) would suggest no, but no sources are given.

Answer (score 31):

It is always difficult to say whether such similarities are just coincidence, or if there was some intended reference. In this case, however, it is most likely just a coincidence. 
When Supergirl was first introduced in 1959, her original secret identity was Linda Lee. She was later (in 1961) adopted by Fred and Edna Danvers and was from then on known as Linda Lee Danvers.
Carol Danvers was first introduced in 1967 in *Marvel Super-Heroes* #13 in the role of Security Chief of a restricted military base, where Danvers meets Dr. Walter Lawson, the human alias of alien Kree hero Captain Marvel (introduced in the same issue). She didn't get any superpowers until 10 years later, in *Ms. Marvel* #1 (1977), and as far as I can see, she didn't appear in any comics between *Captain Marvel* #18 in 1969 (where she sustained severe injuries) and *Ms. Marvel* #1. It seems that originally, she was not intended to be a superheroine, and hence it is unlikely that she is named for Supergirl's alias.

Comment: I have to jump in to note that Carol Danvers, head of Cape Security, appeared in "Avengers" #90 (1971).  This was in the run-up issues to the famous Kree-Skrull War.  The Avengers had taken Mar-Vell to the Cape where specialized equipment could purge him of accumulated Negative Zone radiation.  A Kree Sentry attacked and mayhem ensued.  Danvers had a cameo appearance, insisting the Avengers do a proper debrief for her reports.

Comment: @Blaze: I just re-read the Kree-Skrull War after seeing the *Captain Marvel* movie. The Carol Danvers we see there turns out to be the Super-Skrull in disguise. There is no mention of the  fate of the real Carol or when the impostor took over her identity.

Comment: A shrewd catch sir! Up until now, I have always assumed the Super Skrull stepped into the identity *after* the scene at the Cape. But re-reading it now, I do believe you are correct!